# FastScroll Behaves Strangely with a Custom ListAdapter which implements SectionIndexer

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, fastscroll

I am working on a ListActivity that has a inner class that is a child of SimpleAdapter that implements SectionIndexer.

```
class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

    HashMap<String, Integer> letters;
    Object[] sections;
    AlphabetIndexer alphaIndexer;
    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
            int resource, String[] from, int[] to, 
            HashMap<String, Integer> letters, Object[] sections) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);

        this.letters = letters;
        this.sections = sections;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.common_image_row1, null);
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> data = (HashMap<String, Object>) getItem(position);
        Integer idArtist = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("idArtist"));

        convertView.setTag(idArtist);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name))
            .setText((String) data.get("sName"));

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        image.setTag((String) data.get("sImageUrl"));           
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_artwork);

        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_count))
            .setText((String) data.get("iSongs") + " Songs");

        if (!bScrolling) {
            new API.DownloadImagesTask().execute(image);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        String letter = (String) sections[section];

        return letters.get(letter);

    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        return sections;
    }
}
```

The activity is receives a JSON object in a separate AysncTask.  This object is made up of various JSONArrays whose keys are first letter of the item the items of the array.  So, the array is made up of a bunch of items that begin with the letter "B".  Therefore, that JSONArray's key is "B".

```
{
    B: ["ball", "buck", "bill"]
    C: ["charlie", "chuck", "chap"]
}
```

The object does not necessarily have all of the letters of the alphabet.  I am also aware that order is not guaranteed with JSONObjects so I sort them.
    List> maps = new ArrayList>();
            ArrayList sections = new ArrayList();
            HashMap letters = new HashMap();

```
        String[] alphabet = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N"
                ,"O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            if (playlistArtists.optJSONArray(alphabet[i]) != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray artists = playlistArtists.getJSONArray(alphabet[i]);
                    sections.add(alphabet[i]);

                    for (int j = 0; j < artists.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject artist = (JSONObject) artists.get(j);
                        HashMap<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("idArtist", artist.getString("idArtist"));
                        map.put("sName", artist.getString("sName"));
                        map.put("sImageUrl", artist.getString("sImageUrl-thumb"));
                        map.put("iSongs", artist.getString("iSongs"));
                        maps.add(map);

                        letters.put(alphabet[i], k);
                        k++;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"JSONException in Music::GetMusicCatlog.doInBackground");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(Catalog.this, 
                maps,
                R.layout.common_image_row1,
                new String[] {"idArtist","sName", "sImageUrl", "iSongs" },
                new int[] {R.id.item_id, R.id.item_name, R.id.item_image, R.id.item_count }, 
                letters, 
                sections.toArray());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem I am having is with FastScroll.  I have everything working for the most part.  The list is grouped by first letter and when using FastScroll the letter appears in the popup and goes to the correct group.  The issue is when I let go of the FastScroll after going to the desired section the FastScroll "Jumps" to a random part of the list.  It doesn't stay in the location where I let go of it.  I think it is going to an arbitrary place in the section because I do not have the SectionIndexer implemented right.  I think the problem is with this method.

```
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

I am just not sure how to implement the SectionIndexer methods properly...

Comment: as a sidenote: getPositionForSection() should return the starting index, not the last index (which you are doing). So, assuming artists is A-Z sorted, either go through artists array backwards or only add the index to the letter hashmap if it's that key does not exist yet (so you'd be adding only the first index)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I saw many time getSectionForPosition implemented in the same way like getPositionForSection

```
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        String letter = (String) sections[section];

        return letters.get(letter);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        String letter = (String) sections[position];

        return letters.get(letter);
    }
```

Comment: I changed your answer a little and it helped a bit.  Its still not perfect though. 'String letter = (String) sections[position]' in getSectionForPosition(int position)

Comment: this does not make any sense to me (just starting with Android). How can you get use item position on section list? If you have 20 items and 3 sections won't getSectionForPosition() be called with position=20 if you fastscroll all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR First answer can't be correct. If you need a sample implementation of the `getSectionForPosition` method, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819394/section-indexer-get-section-for-position-returns-0/29318889#29318889).

You're right, it looks like a problem with your implementation of `getSectionForPosition`. **The answer** provided so far **can't be correct** because you need to return the index of the section a certain position is related to and not the position a section is related to (that is what you `getPositionForSection` method should do).

So you should rework your `getSectionForPosition` method (again). You need a valid mapping for every *position* to a *section*. Documentation says:

> Given a position within the adapter, returns the index of the corresponding section within the array of section objects.

If you need an example of how to build such a mapping, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819394/section-indexer-get-section-for-position-returns-0/29318889#29318889). Implemented correctly, it will solve the problem of a jumping scrollbar and instead will position it properly.