# section indexer get section for position returns 0

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, sectionindexer

In my project I have class that extends `ArrayAdapter<String>` and implements `SectionIndexer`. When implementing methods `getPositionForSection` and `getSectionForPosition` I have found some strange behaviour.

Why section indexer works properly when `getSectionForPosition` returns 0?

```
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

this implementation is used in many tutorials, for example:

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-listview-fastscroll/

http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html

Documentation says that

> Given a position within the adapter, returns the index of the
>   corresponding section within the array of section objects.

so if my list have 5 items starting with letter "A" and some items starting with letter "B", then getSectionForPosition(5) should return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the basic functionality of the `sectionIndexer` (scrolling through the section indices when pulling the scrollbar thumb) is unaffected, returning a constant in the method `getSectionForPosition` can lead to a misbehaviour of the scrollbar positioning when swiping through the list (e.g. the scrollbar moving out of the window on the y-axis).

Apparently this misbehaviour only occurs when the list or single sections exceed a certain length, so for shorter lists the indexer might seem to work correctly (but in fact doesn't). I experienced this misbehaviour in larger lists when returning a constant in the above method several times and fixed it by implementing `getSectionForPosition` in a correct way.

---

However, since it might be interesting for others I can provide a sample implementation of that method. Let `azIndexer` be a `HashMap` containing a correct `section -> position` mapping of my indices and `listItems` be the items arranged by the adapter. The following builds a `position -> sectionIndex` mapping stored in `positionIndexer`.

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList();
for (int i : azIndexer.values()) {
    values.add(i);
}
values.add(listItems.size()-1);
Collections.sort(values);

int k = 0;
int z = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < values.size()-1; i++) {
    int temp = values.get(i+1);
    do {
        positionIndexer.put(k, z);
        k++;
    } while(k < temp);
    z++;
}
```

which will then be used in the `getSectionForPosition` method:

```
@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return positionIndexer.get(position);
}
```

Comment: (e.g. the scrollbar moving out of the window on the y-axis)  <----  OMG, been head-banging on desk wondering why this happens when fast scrolling is enabled. Thanks for the sample implementation, as it really helps explains some of the things I never knew about.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback method getPositionForSection(int section) needs to be implemented to give the right position which is used by setSelection to return the right position where you want to scroll on touch of SectionIndexer on rightside.

Make sure you are doing this

```
this.setSelection(((SectionIndexer) getAdapter()) .getPositionForSection(currentPosition));
```

You need to implement two callback methods

```
@Override
public Object[] getSections() { 
  Log.d("ListView", "Get sections"); 
  String[] sectionsArr = new String[sections.length()]; 
  for (int i=0; i < sections.length(); i++) 
  sectionsArr[i] = "" + sections.charAt(i);

   return sectionsArr; 
 }
```

This final callback and you are done here

```
@Override 
public int getPositionForSection(int section){ 
  Log.d("ListView", "Get position for section"); 
  for (int i=0; i < this.getCount(); i++) { 
  String item = this.getItem(i).toLowerCase(); 
  if (item.charAt(0) == sections.charAt(section)) 

 return i; 
} 

return 0; 
}
```